# JTextArea and JTextField internal padding on text

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea

I would like to increase the spacing / padding / insets for the [JTextField](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) and [JTextArea](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html). Effectively increase the spacing between the two red lines in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could also try using an EmptyBorder to put in gaps between the two components.  If you already have a Border, you can use that in conjunction with an EmptyBorder to create a CompoundBorder.  In the code fragment below, a new CompoundBorder is created that has a TitledBorder and an EmptyBorder which enforces a padding of 1 pixed around the component.

```
testPanel.setBorder(
   javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
      javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
         null, "Border Title",
         javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION,
         javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION,
         new java.awt.Font("Verdana", 1, 11)
      ),
      javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1)
   )
);
```

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried the setMargin method?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this is:

```
yourVariableName.setMargin(new Insets(2,2,2,2));
```

The digits represent (top, left, bottom, right). Works for both JTextField and JTextArea