# Centering JButton in BoxLayout, JTextField padding

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, boxlayout

I've created simple `JDialog` to gain initial data for my application. Elements (`JLabel`, `JTextField` and `JButton`) are arranged by `BoxLayout` inside the `BorderLayout`. (Code at the end). So far it looks like this:

[image: Current arrangement]

I have two problems:

1. I would like to center `JButton` in it's row. I tried `startBtn.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);`, but it doesn't work properly, mess appears.
2. I want to add some left/right padding to `TextField`. First solution from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286881/jtextarea-and-jtextfield-internal-padding-on-text) works fine, but other elements are moved right left padding value.

Can anybody give a hint how to place it? I'm new to Java and have no idea.

Here's code of my `InitDialog` class:

```
public class InitDialog extends JDialog {

    JTextField dataTF;
    JButton startBtn;

    public InitDialog(JFrame owner) {

        super(owner, "Rozpocznij test", Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
        initUI();

    }

    public final void initUI() {

        System.out.println("InitDialog::initUI");

        JPanel outer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel inner = new JPanel();

        outer.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20)));

        JLabel msg = new JLabel("<html>Podaj ilości liczb w zestawach testowych<br />(przedzielone średnikiem):");
        inner.add(msg);
        inner.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15));

        dataTF = new JTextField();
        dataTF.setBorder(null);
        dataTF.setText("50; 100; 200");
        inner.add(dataTF);
        inner.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15));

        startBtn = new JButton("Rozpocznij test");
        inner.add(startBtn);

        inner.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inner, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        outer.add(inner);
        add(outer);

        setSize(300, 180);

        //setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(getRootPane());

    }

}
```

Comment: For your 1st question have you tried `inner.add(startBtn,BorderLayout.CENTER);`

Comment: There is no difference in layout then. Thanks for interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BoxLayout alignment is not what you think it is.

To get what you want this is the line you need

```
msg.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```